# cplex - minimization and sum of matrix values and indexes

Tags: java, matrix, cplex

I'm using a Cplex Java API for the first time.

I want to minimize the sum of values in matrix on some indexes, which is given by condition.

For example, if I have the matrix `M = {{ 0, 1, 2, 1},{ 1, 2, 1, 0},{ 0, 1, 1, 0},{ 1, 1, 1, 2}}`.

I want to calculate two sums, first, the sum of all elements `e = 1` and second, indexes where elements are equal to `1`.

So, indexes where element is equal `1` are `{{0,1} {1,0} {1,2} {2,1} {2,2} {3,0} {3,1} {3,2}`.

Result for first case is 9 (1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)` and for second case is 24 (0+1+1+0+1+2+2+1+2+2+3+0+3+1+3+2).

I'm not sure how to use `IloNumVar[]` and create an expression using `IloLinearNumExpr` which is used in sum and minimize a function, while matrix `M` is type `int[][]`.

Comment: If `M` is of type `int[][]`, then there is no need to use CPLEX here. Instead you can just write two loops, that scan through `M` and compute the desired values. What exactly are the variables that can be changed by the optimizer in your case?

Answer (score 0):

In your problem description, there is nothing to optimize. All elements in your matrix `M` are constant. So the two sums you described can be computed directly without involving a tool like CPLEX.